# ASP.NET Core 3 Migrations - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 web api projects. I'm using PostgreSQL as the database and Npgsql as the data provider to connect the database to the project.
I recently updated my model to have a one-to-many relationship and I can't create the new migration needed to use the updated schema in the database.
It's giving me this error when running `dotnet ef migrations add UpdatedPhoto`

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Unable to create an object of type 'MoodContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Here are the files involved:
MoodContext.cs

```
// ... (using and namespaces)
  public class MoodContext : DbContext
  {
    public MoodContext(DbContextOptions<MoodContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Mood> Moods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AuthoredPhoto> AuthoredPhotos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<AuthoredPhoto>();
      modelBuilder.Entity<Mood>().HasMany(m => m.Photos).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
  }
// ...
```

Mood.cs

```
// ... (using and namespaces)
  public class Mood
  {
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("display_name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("photos")]
    public List<AuthoredPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
  }

  public class AuthoredPhoto
  {
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("url")]
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("author_url")]
    public Uri AuthorUrl { get; set; }
  }
// ...
```

I don't know what to do. Can someone help me?

Edit:
Here's the Startup.cs file as requested in the comments.

```
// ... (using and namespaces)
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      // Creating the Connection URI
      string host = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:POSTGRES_HOST"];
      string port = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:POSTGRES_PORT"];
      string db = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:POSTGRES_DB"];
      string user = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:POSTGRES_USER"];
      string password = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:POSTGRES_PASSWORD"];
      string maxPoolSize = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MAX_POOL_SIZE"];
      string connectionString = $"Host={host};Port={port};Username={user};Password={password};Database={db};Maximum Pool Size={maxPoolSize};";
      // Hangfire configuration
      services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UsePostgreSqlStorage(connectionString));
      services.AddHangfireServer();
      // Setting up the database for the MoodContext
      services.AddDbContext<MoodContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
      // Adding the controllers
      services.AddControllers();
      // Getting the environment variables
      string pexels = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PEXELS");
      // Checking whether the env var is set
      if (pexels == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException();
      // Setting up the clients
      services.AddHttpClient("spotify", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.spotify.com"));
      services.AddHttpClient("spotify_accounts", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://accounts.spotify.com"));
      services.AddHttpClient("pexels", c =>
      {
        // Setting the address
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.pexels.com");
        // Setting the authorization header
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", pexels);
        // Wait for the response
        c.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000;
      });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

      app.UseHttpsRedirection()
         .UseRouting()
         .UseAuthorization()
         .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());

      // Initialization of the PhotoUpdater job (running monthly)
      RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<PhotoUpdater>(job => job.Run(), Cron.Monthly());
    }
  }
// ...
```

Here's the Program.cs file

```
// ...(using and namespaces)
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => config.AddEnvironmentVariables())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
  }
// ...
```

Comment: Did you tried putting first the line base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);? and not in the end of the method?

Comment: @rekiem87 Just tried it now. Still the same error.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.This error may result from your Startup.cs.Could you please share your Startup.cs?

Comment: @Rena I've aded the Startup.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the link provided by the exception you can see the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory).

> You can also tell the tools how to create your DbContext by implementing the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface: If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived DbContext or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the DbContext and use the design-time factory instead.

The problem here is that your services are not registered using the Startup when running `dotnet ef` commands.

You need to create an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>`.

Something like this:

```cs
public class MoodContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public MoodContextFactory CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        // you can also use user-secrets, environment-variables or what ever you need here
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MoodContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(configuratio.GetConnectionString("My-ConnectionString"));

        return new MoodContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your changes, it now creates the migration but it still gives me the warning: `An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`. At least I can go on.

Comment: @AlessandroLioi when does it produce that error? During startup? Which class?

Comment: @AlessandroLioi is it possible to share the project on github? Then I could look into it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't share it because it's a private project. What I posted is exactly what I changed from the previous working commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try add forgein key and navigation property to the photo class:

```
public long MoodId{ get; set; }
public Mood Mood { get; set; }
```

and change onModelCreating method to:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<AuthoredPhoto>()
      .HasOne(ap => ap.Mood)
      .WithMany(m => m.Photos)
      .HasForeginKey(ap => ap.MoodId)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.

This looks like a problem with your `Program` or `Startup` class throwing an exception. It's not that your model is wrong, it's that entity framework can't work out how to construct your DbContext right now.

Comment: Hi I've added both of them

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly registeted the db context in the Configure method on the Startup class.

services.AddDbContext(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnString");

Replace the UseSqlServer with the Postgresql equivalent.

Comment: This is my db context registration: `services.AddDbContext<MoodContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));`. It should be correct.